# Overriding the event listener in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to Override the event handler of add button to update after clicking on change event button. but the code is not working

```js
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click",function(){
  add();  
  document.getElementById("change_event").value="Now change the event";
  document.getElementById("change_event").style.display="block";
});

document.getElementById("change_event").addEventListener("click",function(){

  document.getElementById("test").value="Update";
  document.getElementById("change_event").style.display="none";
  
  document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click",function(){
      update();  
  });  
});

function add(){
  alert("Add");
}
function update(){
  alert("Update"); 
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="add" id="test" name="add">
<input type="button" name="change_event" style="display: none" value="change Event" id="change_event">
```

when i click on add the `add()` function will call. when I clicked on `Now change the event` update button appear and after clicking on update button the update function must be called.

My problem is, update button calls to `add()` function at very first time.
When I click on update then only `update()` must be called

Answer (score 2):

When adding events, they are stacking one on another, means you can have more than one click event on same element, so they not overwrite eachother. You must use [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) to first remove previous event and only then assign new one

```
var eventWithAdd = function(){
    add();      
    document.getElementById("change_event").value="Now change the event";
    document.getElementById("change_event").style.display="block";

}

...

document.getElementById("test")
    .removeEventListener('click', eventWithAdd)
    .addEventListener('click', function () {update()});
```

Answer (score 1):

What you should use is [`removeElementListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) to unregister the `add()` function and register the `update()` function:

```js
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", eventListenerAdd);
document.getElementById("change_event").addEventListener("click", eventListenerUpdate);

function eventListenerAdd(){
    add();      
    document.getElementById("change_event").value="Now change the event";
    document.getElementById("change_event").style.display="block";

};


function eventListenerUpdate(){
    document.getElementById("test").value="Update";
    document.getElementById("change_event").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("test").removeEventListener("click", eventListenerAdd);
        document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click",function(){
            update();       
        });   
};

function add(){
    alert("Add");
}
function update(){
alert("Update");    
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="add" id="test" name="add">
<input type="button" name="change_event" style="display: none" value="change Event" id="change_event">
```

As you can see, you need to add the Eventlisteners as actual functions with a name in order to remove them.

Comment: Well not really 'with a name', you just have to store the instance. `const handler = () => update()` would work too, if you add and remove handler from the listener.

Comment: That's what I meant